# oracle double data sorting

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I would like to sort the below kind of data

```
ms3_fldr01
ms14_fldr01
ms13_fldr01
ms13_fldp01
ms30_fldr01
ms20_fldp01
ms9_fldr01
ms14_fldp01
ms4_fldp01
ms5_fldr01
ms1_fldp01
ms3_fldr01
ms8_fldr01
```

In such a way that fldp01 will appear first and then fldr01 . 
In first appeared  data set of fldp01  first (ms) part has to be sorted ( ms1...ms10)  also in fldr01 data set  first (ms) part has to be sorted . Like below

```
ms1_fldp01
ms4_fldp01
ms13_fldp01
ms14_fldp01
ms20_fldp01
ms3_fldr01
ms5_fldr01
ms8_fldr01
ms9_fldr01
ms13_fldr01
ms14_fldr01
ms30_fldr01
```

I have tried in below way but that is not giving data set as per expectation.

```
select
    server, count(*) as C
from TEST
where d_updated_date >= trunc(sysdate-4) 
group by server
order by
    replace(replace(server,'_fldr01'),'ms') desc,
    (case when substr(server,instr(server,'_')+1)='fldp01' then 1 
          when substr(server,instr(server,'_')+1)='fldp02' then 2 
          else 0 end) desc;
```

Can you please help here ??

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want:

```
order by (case when server like '%_fldp%' then 1 else 2 end),
         length(server),
         server
```

(Note:  I know that underscore is a special character in `like` but the above will still work.)

This depends on the fact that the part after the `_` is fixed in length.  Otherwise, you will need to do a bit more work to separate out the first component.

Comment: How does this sort `ms1_fldp01` ahead of `ms4_fldp01`?

Comment: Because the two strings have the same "fldp" pattern, they have the same length, and then the strings are sorted alphabetically.  You sometimes seem like a pretty smart guy.  I would think that this is obvious.  The downvote is rude.

Comment: OH...  I missed the third criterion, `server`. I disagree with your last observation (about downvotes). I use upvotes and downvotes to mark answers that I believe to be correct vs. not so. As in this case, sometimes I am wrong. (I am sure I am sometimes wrong on upvotes, too.) I very rarely leave a comment when I upvote, but I always leave a comment when I downvote, which is why you may think I always downvote your posts. But none of that has to do with rudeness; I do my best to make this site helpful, using the tools it provides.

Comment: I just realized I made another mistake though, and for that I apologize. Sometimes I do it right, but not always. The "right" use of the tools is to ask my question, and if I don't get an answer, or if I think the answer is still wrong, THEN downvote. That's what I should have done.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I'm not having any more discussion on the topic, but downvoting a correct answer is simply rude.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The mathguy is simply rude...to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr`:

```
select *
from test
order by regexp_substr(server, '_\w+'),
  to_number(regexp_substr(server, '\d+'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a solution using ordinary string functions to outperform a regex-based solution.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    LENGTH(SUBSTR(server, INSTR(server, '_') + 1)),
    SUBSTR(server, INSTR(server, '_') + 1),
    LENGTH(SUBSTR(server, 1, INSTR(server, '_') - 1)),
    SUBSTR(server, 1, INSTR(server, '_') - 1)
```